# how to resolve ModuleNotFoundError python error

Tags: python-3.x, apache-spark, model-view-controller, airflow

```
exampleProject
--> models   
----> database
-------> __init__.py
-------> example1.py
-------> example1.py
--> services
----> __init__.py
----> service1.py
----> service1.py
```

i have created this table structure for my project and the problem is when i am importing example1.py file in service1.py i am getting **ModuleNotFoundError** and same error getting when importing service2.py file in example2.py

i have tried sys.path.append method. but still getting same error, files imported in **init**.py file.

i want to run this project in production, i had read somewhere its not good practice to use sys.path.append method in production.

this is normal structure of folder but if i want to increase folders and file and import file from various folder how can i do that?
can somebody help me in this, how to resolve this problem.

thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, the dags folder gets added to the sys path. Hence anything inside dags folder can be imported in Airflow env.

I will take an example that you have given. So let's consider the below folder structure resides inside dags folder eg `/home/airflow/dags`

```
exampleProject
--> models   
----> database
-------> __init__.py
-------> example1.py
--> services
----> __init__.py
----> service1.py
```

Lets assume that `exampleProject/models/database/example1.py` looks something like this

```
def example1_func():
    print("In example1_func")
```

Now, let's import the above function inside the `services/service1.py`, so below is how we will import the `example1_func`

```
from exampleProject.models.database.example1 import example1_func

def service1_func():
    example1_func()
    print('inside service1_func')
```

Now we can call the `service1_func` in our tasks by importing in similar method

```
from exampleProject.services.service1 import service1_func

# creating dag
...


# calling the function in a task
service1_func()
...
```

Comment: thank you @akash, i did using sys.path,insert(0,os.getcwd()) after addding this, its worked for me